Am I understanding the で condition/scope marker right?
The question is:
僕の知っている限りでは彼は家出しました
I've seen this 限りで been used a lot and I am wondering does the で here with ''限り'' indicate scope/condition? Because of this confusion I ended up compiling some more example sentences for clarification.
If these are scope/condition, am I correct with my understanding?

Examples:
僕の知っている限りでは彼は家出しました
(Indicates scope of knowledge) [Within the limits of what I know]
頑張るだけではだめ
(Indicates that the condition of just doing one's best is not enough)
僕のまけでいい
(Indicates that losing is an okay condition)
あっ あと天国って場所で何か思い当たることないですか？
(Indicates scope of knowledge (?) [When it comes to/In Terms of X place]
割引で食べ物を買った
(Indicates condition of the purchase) (?)
確認で彼女に聞いた
(Indicates condition of questioning) (?)  (Still a bit confusing for me)
[I asked her for confirmation] (I asked her under the condition of confirmation)
追加で50個注文しました
(Indicates condition of purchase)
[I ordered 50 more in addition / as an addition]

Summary:
Within the scope of (something) ~ (something else) applies
見ている限りではなんともなさそう
Doing an action under the condition of (something)
追加でケーキを買った
Being under a condition of (something) ~ (something else) applies
僕のまけでいい
It seems like で in general is the context particle for whatever comes after.
(I apologize for the long post and errors (if there are any) by the way.
Please let me know if I am wrong.)

Yes, your understanding seems generally correct. Please keep in mind that you ultimately have to remember each phrase individually. The English preposition corresponding to this type of で varies from phrase to phrase (though it's usually one of "in", "on", "with" or "at"). In particular, the distinction between で and に does not always appear logical. See: 後で vs. 前に. Why not the same particle?

''ライバル関係で/は絶対嫌だろうなって
being [in] a rival relationship is the condition''
''おにぎり一個だけで/はお腹がすく。
Just [with] one onigiri is the condition''
''頑張るだけではダメなんです
Just [by] doing one's best is the condition''
''今のレベルで試験に受かることは無理だ
[At] this level is the condition''
Yeah I got it now.. jesus christ. I apologize for the amount of spam questions. Long Covid completely wiped out my knowledge and I completely forgot...

@HoodIntercooledSubaru In "ライバル関係では嫌" and "頑張るだけではダメ", I think で is originally the te-form of the copula だ. But it's probably best to think of this type of では simply as "if".

Appreciate the comment a lot, I will add this point to my Anki card to refresh my mind

The full context is: ''だから２人がライバル関係では絶対嫌だろうなって'' but I assume the copula だ and では (if) meaning of it is still correct
